# Cannot log in to local admin

Tags: terminal, command-line, user-account

I copied this script and made the changes on it, but for some reason when I try to log in with the account it doesn't log in at all.

Has anyone experienced this issue? I am wondering what could be the cause because it was not an issue before, so why is it now.

I was able to log in 8/10/2021 but I deleted it because my colleague couldn't log in on his machine, so I ran the script again and I am having similar issues.

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/rc.common
sudo dscl . create /Users/admin
sudo dscl . create /Users/admin RealName *****
sudo dscl . create /Users/admin hint Old
sudo dscl . passwd /Users/admin *****
sudo dscl . create /Users/admin UniqueID 10023
sudo dscl . create /Users/admin PrimaryGroupID 70
sudo dscl . create /Users/admin UserShell /bin/zsh
sudo dscl . create /Users/admin NFSHomeDirectory /Local/Users/admin
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership admin
sudo chown -R admin:staff /Users/admin
sudo cp -R /System/Library/User\ Template/English.lproj /Users/admin
```

Comment: I'm guessing, but I think the choice of 501 could be what broke it. 501 should always exist as the first admin account made, others should increment from there, 502, 503 etc

Comment: I added my actual edit on the script so you can see what I had. Let me know what I am doing wrong and why for some reason it does not want to log in but lets me make changes with that account.

Comment: Where did you get this script from? Shouldn‘t you switch the last two lines?

Comment: And create the actual home directory somewhere?

Comment: I got this script from here, what exactly would I need to change from the bottom? Because the change I did is made the name same as my local admin account, so it can match. Like everything works when manually putting it on Terminal just can't log in to it.